# Pixi: SVG not scaling as expected

Tags: pixi.js

The following link demonstrates the issue:

1. When using the beeSvg as the source, changing scales changes the resolution of the sprite as it should.
2. When using the custom simpleIcon as the source, the sprite instead is cut off.

https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/pkT96MYIfGmkiYwjtgvGT